# issues creating a class that handles contacts

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

All along I have been handling contacts within the CCPhysicsSprite class since I mainly set the userdata to a CCPhysicsSprite. As below:

ContactListenerClass.mm:

```
void ContactListenerClass:: BeginContact(b2Contact *contact){

b2Fixture       *fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
b2Fixture       *fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();
b2Body          *fixtureABody = fixtureA->GetBody();
b2Body          *fixtureBBody = fixtureB->GetBody();

CCPhysicsSprite* physicsSprite = (CCPhysicsSprite*)fixtureABody->GetUserData();
CCPhysicsSprite* physicsSprite2 = (CCPhysicsSprite*)fixtureBBody->GetUserData();

[physicsSprite spritesHadContact:physicsSprite2];

}
```

The spritesHadContact method is in the CCPhysicsSprite.mm class:

```
-(void)spritesHadContact:(CCPhysicsSprite*)secondPhysicsSprite {
    int tag1 = self.tag;
    int tag2 = secondPhysicsSprite.tag;

    if ((tag1 == 30) && (tag2 == 40 )) || ((tag1 == 40) && (tag2 == 30))  {
      CCLOG(@"proceed to handle contact");
    }
```

The above example is a bit straight forward. But when I started creating and destroying joints I realized it would be better to have a class other than the CCPhysicsSprite that does handles contacts. I made a class (contactHandler) that does that, but it's not working. I don't know what I've done wrong. Please see below:

ContactHandler.h:

```
#import "CCPhysicsSprite.h"

@interface ContactHandler : CCPhysicsSprite {

}

-(void)spritesHadContact:(CCPhysicsSprite*)firstPhysicsSprite otherSprite:(CCPhysicsSprite*)secondPhysicsSprite;

@end
```

ContactHandler.mm:

```
#import "ContactHandler.h"

@implementation ContactHandler

-(void)spritesHadContact:(CCPhysicsSprite*)firstPhysicsSprite otherSprite:(CCPhysicsSprite*)secondPhysicsSprite {
int tag1 = firstPhysicsSprite.tag;
int tag2 = secondPhysicsSprite.tag;

    if ((tag1 == 30) && (tag2 == 40 )) || ((tag1 == 40) && (tag2 == 30))  {
      CCLOG(@"proceed to handle contact");
}
@end
```

ContactListenerClass.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Box2D.h"
#import "ContactHandler.h"


class ContactListenerClass : public b2ContactListener    {
public:
    ContactHandler* contactHandler;

       void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact);

};
```

ContactListenerClass.mm:

```
#import "ContactListenerClass.h"
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"


void ContactListenerClass:: BeginContact(b2Contact *contact)
{


b2Fixture       *fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
b2Fixture       *fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();
b2Body          *fixtureABody = fixtureA->GetBody();
b2Body          *fixtureBBody = fixtureB->GetBody();

CCPhysicsSprite* physicsSprite = (CCPhysicsSprite*)fixtureABody->GetUserData();
CCPhysicsSprite* physicsSprite2 = (CCPhysicsSprite*)fixtureBBody->GetUserData();

[contactHandler spritesHadContact:physicsSprite otherSprite:physicsSprite2];

}
```

**UPDATED**

The spritesHadContact method in the ContactHandler class is not printing the CCLOG to the console. I tried a CCLOG to see which contacts were taking place but the method does not recognize any contacts.

Comment: Please explain what the issues are. "Not working" is not working for me...

Comment: @iforce2d: I just updated the question.

Comment: "contactHandler" object inside the listener is not initialised?

Comment: @Hamdullahshah: I am not really sure what to initialize my "contactHandler" to.